# Verify expectations in datatable after datatable input from previous step

Tags: java, datatable, cucumber

My feature file is:

```
 Scenario: New Application: Verify Verifycation Message
  Given user on Consumer Enquiry page as Internal Admin
  And user select New Application for Enquiry Type
  When user enters InputFileds to verify
|Product_Type|Member_Reference|ID_Number|ID_Expairy_Date|Date_of_Birth|Eng_Family_Name|Eng_First_Name|Arab_Family_Name|Arab_First_Name|
  ||||||||||
  |Credit Card|||||||||
  Then user should see Messages for the inputs
  |Message_Product_Type|Message_Member_Reference|Message_ID_Number|Message_ID_Expairy_Date|Message_Date_of_Birth|Message_Family_Name|Message_First_Name|
    |You must select the Product Type from the list.|You must enter the Member Reference.|You must enter the ID Number.|You must enter the ID Expiry Date.|You must enter the Date of Birth.|You must enter a Family Name.|You must enter a First Name.|
    ||You must enter the Member Reference.|You must enter the ID Number.|You must enter the ID Expiry Date.|You must enter the Date of Birth.|You must enter a Family Name.|You must enter a First Name.|
```

What I want to archive is to verify different output from the same page after type in different input.

my step definitions are like this:

```
@When("^user enters InputFileds to verify$")
public void user_enters_InputFileds_to_verify(List<ConsumerInputContext> consumerInputs) throws Throwable {
    pom.switchToMainFrame();
    for (ConsumerInputContext inputs : consumerInputs) {
        Wait.untilJqueryIsDone(testContext.getWebDriverManager().getDriver());
        consumerPage.sendProductType(inputs.getProduct_Type());
        consumerPage.sendMemberRef(inputs.getMember_Reference());
        consumerPage.sendIdNumberIpt(inputs.getID_Number());
        consumerPage.sendIdExpiryDateIpt(inputs.getID_Expairy_Date());
        consumerPage.sendDateOfBirthIpt(inputs.getDate_of_Birth());
        consumerPage.sendEngFamilyNameIpt(inputs.getEng_Family_Name());
        consumerPage.sendEngFirstNameIpt(inputs.getEng_First_Name());
        consumerPage.sendArabFamilyNameIpt(inputs.getArab_Family_Name());
        consumerPage.sendArabFirstNameIpt(inputs.getArab_First_Name());
        consumerPage.clickOnAddressButton();
        Wait.untilJqueryIsDone(testContext.getWebDriverManager().getDriver());
    }
    pom.switchToDefault();

}

@Then("user should see Messages for the inputs")
public void user_should_see_Messages_for_the_inputs(List<ConsumerInputMessage> msgTable) throws Throwable {
    pom.switchToMainFrame();
    System.out.println("consumerInputs.size=>" + msgTable.size());
    Wait.untilJqueryIsDone(testContext.getWebDriverManager().getDriver());
    List<String> actualMessages = consumerPage.getMessages();
    List<String> exptMessages = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (ConsumerInputMessage messages : msgTable) {
        if (!messages.getMessage_Product_Type().isEmpty())
            exptMessages.add(messages.getMessage_Product_Type());
        if (!messages.getMessage_Member_Reference().isEmpty())
            exptMessages.add(messages.getMessage_Member_Reference());
        if (!messages.getMessage_ID_Number().isEmpty())
            exptMessages.add(messages.getMessage_ID_Number());
        if (!messages.getMessage_ID_Expairy_Date().isEmpty())
            exptMessages.add(messages.getMessage_ID_Expairy_Date());
        if (!messages.getMessage_Date_of_Birth().isEmpty())
            exptMessages.add(messages.getMessage_Date_of_Birth());
        if (!messages.getMessage_Family_Name().isEmpty())
            exptMessages.add(messages.getMessage_Family_Name());
        if (!messages.getMessage_First_Name().isEmpty())
            exptMessages.add(messages.getMessage_First_Name());
    }
    Assert.assertEquals(actualMessages, exptMessages);
}
```

But it looks like each step function runs the whole datatable then run the next step function. which will end up the I can only get the response from last set of input file, and the datatable I am going to verify contains the whole set of data.

Can any body share what is your solution for this situation? I think it's quite common in real life.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at using a scenariooutline instead of a datatable. The ScenarioOutline will run the complete set of steps of a scenario for each dataset.

```
Scenario Outline: New Application: Verify Verifycation Message
  Given user on Consumer Enquiry page as Internal Admin
  And user select New Application for Enquiry Type
  When user enters InputFileds to verify
    |Product_Type|Member_Reference|
    |<product_type>|<member_reference>|
  Then user should see Messages for the inputs
   |Message_Product_Type|Message_Member_Reference|
   |message_product_type>|<message_member_reference>|

  Examples:
      | Product_Type|Member_Reference|Message_Product_Type|Message_Member_Reference|
      | product type 1 |member reference 1|Message PT1|Message MR1|
      | product type 2 |member reference 2|Message PT2|Message MR2|
```

Refer to this - http://www.baeldung.com/cucumber-scenario-outline

Comment: Thank you for answering. I dont want to use scenario outline because I dont want to run the whole process again with a new window where only check the verification message of the web elements.

Comment: but I have found solution to my problem now. Thank you anyway!